# How to assign variables using dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, variables, dynamic-sql

I need to assign two variables(tmp_x and tmp_y) with dynamic sql, because I need to select the right table at runtime. the sql as below:

```
 updateSql:= 'select p.gis_x,p.gis_y into tmp_x,tmp_y from  publish_'
             ||splitCollection(indexs).city_no ||'.t_customer p 
             where p.customer_id=:1 and p.gis_x is not null and p.gis_y is not null';

 execute immediate updateSql using splitCollection(indexs).CUSTOMER_ID;
```

the compilation is OK ,but occur the runtime error about "lack of keyword",  how can I fix that?

Comment: "My car is not working, please tell me how I can make it work." Do you see the problem with that request - and the analogy to the way you asked your question? HOW is it "not working"? What happens - do you get a compilation error? A runtime error? Does it run but produces no output, or the wrong output?

Comment: @mathguy sorry about My poor English, compilation is OK, and  runtime error is "lack of keyword" in Chinese, I don't know if I translate right about it

Comment: OK, so the SQL `SELECT` statement generated in the code appears to be an invalid SQL query. Instead of "execute immediate", export the statement as text (use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(updateSql)`) and inspect it and/or try to run it. Do you get the same error? Post the exact string `updateSql` here for more help.

Comment: I think you're just missing `returning into` clause. Remove that from the select statement `into tmp_x,tmp_y` and add it like so: `execute immediate updateSql using splitCollection(indexs).CUSTOMER_ID into tmp_x,tmp_y;`.

Comment: @g00dy thanks It solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following the comments:

This:

```
 updateSql:= 'select p.gis_x,p.gis_y into tmp_x,tmp_y from  publish_'
             ||splitCollection(indexs).city_no ||'.t_customer p 
             where p.customer_id=:1 and p.gis_x is not null and p.gis_y is not null';

 execute immediate updateSql using splitCollection(indexs).CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Needs to become:

```
 updateSql:= 'select p.gis_x,p.gis_y from  publish_'
             ||splitCollection(indexs).city_no ||'.t_customer p 
             where p.customer_id=:1 and p.gis_x is not null and p.gis_y is not null';

 execute immediate updateSql using splitCollection(indexs).CUSTOMER_ID RETURNING into tmp_x,tmp_y;
```

The difference is the into clause, which, when used with `execute immediate` should go in the actual statement and not be part of the `Select` statement.

Cheers